# Extracting data with Vlookup and checking values with Arrayformula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I need to extract data from one tab (extracted data) to another tab and validate the data in the following way:

if 0% assign 3
if from 0 till -10% assign 2
if from -10% and more assign 1
if from 0% till 10% assign 4
if from 10% and more assign 5

here is the link to the file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f8SFi2hNP6Anav7G7BYWyK-fasPk1pT1A2HFJblT-FI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use two vlookups.

If you have a tab called 'Ranges' with the following two columns:

```
Percentage  Result
-1000%      1
-10%        2
0%          3
10%         4
11%         5
```

[image]

Then the formula in cell `B1` on the 'calculations' tab would be something like:

```
=arrayformula({"Con Potential";iferror(vlookup(vlookup(A2:A,'Extracted data'!A:D,4,0),Ranges!A:B,2,1),)})
```

Delete all data below cell `B1` for the `arrayformula` to work correctly.

The second vlookup references col D on the 'Extracted data' tab because that is the percentage I think you are comparing? If not, alter `4` in the vlookup to another column.

[image]

If it helps, please see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

**NB**: In place of `Ranges!A:B` you could use a fixed array:

```
=arrayformula({"Con Potential";iferror(vlookup(vlookup(A2:A,'Extracted data'!A:D,4,0),{-10,1;-0.1,2;0,3;0.1,4;0.11,5},2,1),)})
```

If you want to temporarily see the fixed array in case you want to edit any values, place this in a cell somewhere out of the way:

```
={-10,1;-0.1,2;0,3;0.1,4;0.11,5}
```

`,` is used to bump to a new column, `;` is used as a return.

**Relevance**

Looking at 'Relevance' lookup from 'Position Delta' and this table in your sheet:

[image]

Since a 'position delta' value of 10 cannot both have a relevance of 5 and 4, I've made the assumption that 10 gets 5. If that is incorrect, then I'll adjust the boundaries.

Add this to cell `C1` on the 'calculations' tab (clearing all cells below):

```
=arrayformula({"Relevance";iferror(vlookup(vlookup(calculations!A2:A,'Extracted data'!A:D,3,0),{0,5;11,4;21,3;31,2;41,1;51,0},2,1),)})
```

The fixed array `{0,5;11,4;21,3;31,2;41,1;51,0}` has these values:

```
0   5
11  4
21  3
31  2
41  1
51  0
```

If you need to change the boundaries so 10 is a 4, not 5, then change the vlookup to use this fixed range `{0,5;10,4;20,3;30,2;40,1;50,0}`:

```
0   5
10  4
20  3
30  2
40  1
50  0
```

`vlookup` is incremental and anything up to 11 will get 5, then 11 to 20 will get 4, 21 to 30 will get 3 and so on.

`,1)` in the vlookup at the far right gets the nearest value match until 'position delta' has reached the next boundary.

Comment: Thank you! It does work! Is there a solution to avoid Ranges tab and include everything into the formula? I need to avoid all the additional tabs.

Comment: Yes, you could replace `Ranges!A:B` with a fixed array: `{-10,1;-0.1,2;0,3;0.1,4;0.11,5}` - I'll update the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much again! I am trying to copy this formula with a bit different data range: Range Result
0-10 5
10-20 4
20-30 3
30-40 2
40-50 1
50-100 0                                                                                                                                                 and cannot understand where the error is: =arrayformula({"Relevance";iferror(vlookup(vlookup(A2:A,'Extracted data'!A:D,3,0),{10,5;20,4;30,3;40,2;50,1;100,0),)})

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, didn't know much about the upvoting!

Comment: Thanks. You don't need both values in each range 'x-y'. I'll edit the solution shortly.

Comment: Updated solution. Let me know if the boundaries are wrong for 'position delta'.

Comment: would you plz check, I don't see any updates.

Comment: In the solution above, under the section 'Relevance'. Page refresh?

Comment: yes, but it looks like the formula does not work, since the cells are empty https://i.imgur.com/sdFQunv.png

Comment: That's the wrong formula. The one above (under the relevance heading) is: `=arrayformula({"Relevance";iferror(vlookup(vlookup(calculations!A2:A,'Extracted data'!A:D,3,0),{0,5;11,4;21,3;31,2;41,1;51,0},2,1),)})`